# Django sperate migrations for seprate tenants with seperate apps,in same database

Tags: django, multi-tenant

I am trying to make two tenants with separate apps and models, the migrate_schemas make migrations for all the apps so need to separate the migrations is it possible

Comment: In that case, I would suggest to use a third party library, for example you can use [django-tenant](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants). For more details, you need to read their [documentation](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: i am using django-tenants but my issue was migrate_schemas migrates all the schemas how to restrict it to particular schema and can we keep models for separte tenants in same database

Comment: That is good to know. Please update the question with your existing implementations of django tenants, because there is no clue in your question regarding that. Also, I am not sure even if its possible to have separate tenant specific migration in same DB(i know its possible in different databases)

Answer (score 0):

Use `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` and `python manage.py migrate <app_name>` for separate app migrations.

Comment: this works for normal migrations but in the tenant and schemas instead of migrate we use migrate_schemas which migrates all the schemas present in the database so needed to know if we could migrate only one schema with seperate number of apps

Comment: yes, you can do that as well using the command.
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>.<model_name>